# admob, java, cordova, android studio technical issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cordova, admob

Im trying to add admob ads to an exisiting application on the play store which is written in html5 and javascript and made using cordova but I'm having trouble initializing and showing the ads... I believe I narrowed the problem down to my MainActivity.java file but I'm not sure.. I would just like to display a banner ad from admob on my application using either cordova or android studio.. Thank you..

I'm using an android device and cordova and as of now when I do the command cordova run android, it looks like it deploys but crashes.

I'm not very familar with java..

can someone more expierenced in java tell me if my code is atleast correct?

[image]

Comment: Oh well the tutorial one is not even java its in kotlin you have written kotlin code in java file how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @MohammedAbidNafi I changed it to Java and updated the picture, thank you but same thing is happening still with this code. The app deploys but crashes. I'm not familiar with java yet. I wrote my application in html5 and JavaScript and would like to display ads on it.

Comment: So can you please post your logcat and have you tested with test ads?